# undefined symbol: _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_cancelm error

Tags: c++, c, linux, cross-compiling, x86-64

I have a C++/C application which needs to be compiled as a 32 bit application (as there are certain third-party libraries only available for 32 bit). However, the compilation as well as the execution will happen on CentOS 6.4 x86_64 machine.

I am using gnu autotools for building. After doing a lot of googling, finally figured a sets of options to give to `./configure` to create 32 bit executables/shared objects. Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to search in `/lib, /usr/lib/, /usr/lib/gcc/...` instead of `/lib64, ...` Verified that all the generated .so and executable are 32 bit by using `file` command.

But I get the error: "`undefined symbol: _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_cancelm`" if I run the executable.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to link to pthreads with `-lpthread`.

GCC adds a [layer of abstraction over pthreads](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_concurrency_impl.html) and this abstraction use weak symbols, so you can build your executable without link error but fail at runtime.

Comment: Did that too - still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a 32bits pthread library on your target host? If not, I guess you need to get one installed. Also inspect the output of `ldd <my-program>` on your target host, this might help you find out what is missing.

Comment: Yes, there is. passed all the library paths returned by `ldd` through `file` and verified that all are 32-bit.

Comment: If you #include <pthread.h> try to put `extern "C"` around it, you never know!

Comment: Also google brings up this https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=178354. Do you happen to have something like `#define __attribute__()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: The constraint is that my code isn't using ptherad - seems like the third-party librray is using it - the headers do include pthreadh

Comment: If so, without at least a link to the documentation of the third-party library you mention, there's no way I can help you. Your third party library may come with a single threaded version and a way to not include pthread (most likely using something like using -DNO_THREADS at the preprocessing stage), you may want to check their docs for something like that.

Comment: So far no luck. Thanks anyway!